# Dark theme of webview doesn't work in AndroidView Jetpack compose

Tags: android, view, android-jetpack-compose, android-webview, editor

Dark theme of webview doesn't work in AndroidView Jetpack compose.

RichEditor extend webview.

No errors. Simply can't apply dark theme to view

```
implementation 'jp.wasabeef:richeditor-android:2.0.0'
@Composable
fun Webview{
  AndroidView(
        factory = { context ->
            RichEditor(context).apply {
                setEditorHeight(40)
                setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10)
                loadCSS("file:///android_asset/style.css")
                if (isFeatureSupported(WebViewFeature.ALGORITHMIC_DARKENING)) {
                    WebSettingsCompat.setAlgorithmicDarkeningAllowed(settings, true)
                }
                setOnTextChangeListener {
                    scope.launch {

                    }
                }
            }
        },
        update = {
        },
        )
}
```

Comment: Did you read [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/webkit/WebSettingsCompat#setAlgorithmicDarkeningAllowed(android.webkit.WebSettings,boolean))? Did you try it on a physical device/emulated device where **"Note: This API and the behaviour described only apply to apps with targetSdkVersion ≥ TIRAMISU."**?

Comment: Yes, I have api 33

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because simply `RichEditor` (or `WebView`) does not support dark mode by itself. You can use public functions to adjust it's look based on dark theme:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Webview() {

    //Colors based on system theme
    val isDark = isSystemInDarkTheme()
    val textColor = remember(key1 = isDark) { if (isDark) Color.White else Color.Black }
    val backgroundColor = remember(key1 = isDark) { if (isDark) Color.Black else Color.White }

    AndroidView(
        factory = { context ->
            RichEditor(context).apply {
                setEditorHeight(40)
                setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10)
                loadCSS("file:///android_asset/style.css")
                //Sets background color
                this.setEditorBackgroundColor(backgroundColor.toArgb())
                //Sets text color                
                this.setEditorFontColor(textColor.toArgb())
                if (isFeatureSupported(WebViewFeature.ALGORITHMIC_DARKENING)) {
                    WebSettingsCompat.setAlgorithmicDarkeningAllowed(settings, true)
                }
                setOnTextChangeListener {
                    scope.launch {

                    }
                }
            }
        },
        update = {

        },
    )
```

Comment: Thanks. But via xml implementation, its work fine. Encounter with problem in migration from xml to jetpack

Comment: And webview support dark theme via WebSettingsCompat.setAlgorithmicDarkeningAllowed

Comment: @Slava For me it's working only with `Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar` theme so if you are using some other themes like material themes (which is now default in android studio new projects) for app, it doesn't work both compose and xml.

Comment: Thanks. I found. It doesn't work without something in android:theme in android manifest file. But can I use some default theme?

Comment: @Slava Try use `ContextThemeWrapper(context,androidx.appcompat.R.style.Theme_AppCompat_DayNight)` in `RichEditor` constructor. This will apply the theme for this view only and DayNight theme will do the dark mode support.

Comment: Thanks, I chose Theme.Material.NoActionBar

Comment: @ Miroslav Hýbler Sorry, but why setAlgorithmicDarkeningAllowed works only then I choose in androidmanifest parent theme with black color?

Comment: In white compose theme I have flickering effect, first I see black theme and then white. But webview works fine.

Comment: @Slava From the docs `If the app's theme is dark and it allows algorithmic darkening, WebView will attempt to darken web content using an algorithm` so i guess you have to you **dark** theme for AlgorithmicDarkening.

Comment: But why in darkColorScheme background = Color.Transparent and it's white, not black for dark theme?

Comment: @Slava Honestly not sure. With these informations i can't think of anything specific, just few assumptions, there is too much places where the background can be changed. Please consider updating the question or asking new one with all the details that are needed.

For now i can't help further.

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem. It was in default theme in android manifest file. I change default theme light/dark before activity creation.